# Запятая в СПП(?)

Tags: запятые, спп, ссп

Действительно, герой нашего повествования не был хадисоведом(,) и по этой причине в его произведениях могут содержаться выдуманные хадисы.
Нужна ли запятая в скобках?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, слово "действительно" не является общим элементом для обеих частей сложносочиненного предложения. Между 1-й и 2-й частью сложного предложения отношения причинно-следственные, поэтому запятая нужна